# Denwer and php: another drive

Tags: php, imagick, drive

I'm using denwer as my wamp-server, o have code, that exports graphics, but on my drive I have little free space, and i want to save this files for example to the `D:` drive.

How would I do this?

Also here is part of my code:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($data))
    { 

         //if($row['GRD_ID'] != "") {
            /* $file_name_jp2 = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jp2";
             $file = fopen ($file_name_jp2, "w");
             fputs($file, $row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);
             fclose($file);
*/

            $file_name_jpg = "TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jp2";
            $file_out_jpg  = str_replace('.jp2', '.jpg', $file_name_jpg);

            file_put_contents($file_name_jpg, $row['GRD_GRAPHIC']);

            // execute imagemagick convert to change to jpeg with quality 40
            exec("/usr/local/ImageMagick/convert $file_name_jpg -quality 20 -format jpg $file_out_jpg");
            unlink($file_name_jpg); // get rid of temp jp2 file


             set_time_limit(0);
             unset($row);
             $l++;
         //}
         $k++;
    }
```

See `$file_name_jpg`

Comment: It is extremely unclear what, exactly, you need help doing, Pavel.

Comment: @Matt for example, my wamp is on C:drive, and php script exports file to it's directory on C:, but how to do saving on D: ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, that code is written for *nix. It wont work on a Windows machine as is.

You will need to update the path of the `convert` executable, to be that of you Windows path, and change `$file_name_jpg`:

```
$file_name_jpg = "D:/TI/" . $table_name . "/" . $row['GRD_ID'] . ".jp2";
```

Assuming you have a folder `TI` on your `D:` drive, and all other nested folders under `TI`

Comment: The issue may then be that your denwer install doesnt have privileges to your Windows drives. Try to mount, or do mount  to see which drives are already mounted.